# Procedure to bold Strings in a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So, I'm working on a procedure that has an entry of a txt file called orders that specifies the number of words to bold and wich words must be bolded. I've managed to to it for one word but when i try with two words the output gets doubled. For example:

```
Input:
2
Ophelia
him

Output:

ACT I
ACT I


SCENE I. Elsinore. A platform before the castle.
SCENE I. Elsinore. A platform before the castle.


FRANCISCO at his post. Enter to him BERNARDO 
FRANCISCO at his post. Enter to *him* BERNARDO
```

Here's my code, can anyone help me? PS: Ignore the boolean I guess.

```
static void bold(char bold, BufferedReader orders, BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out) throws IOException
{
    String linha = in.readLine();
    boolean encontrou = false;
    String[] palavras = new String[Integer.parseInt(orders.readLine())];
    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++)
    {
        palavras[i] = orders.readLine();
    }

    while (linha != null)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(linha);
        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length && !encontrou; i++)
        {

            if (linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i]) != -1)
            {
                str.insert((linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i])), bold);
                str.insert((linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i])) + palavras[i].length() + 1, bold);
                out.write(str.toString());
                out.newLine();

            }
            else
            {
                out.write(linha);
                out.newLine();
            }
        }
        linha = in.readLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: edit ur code to add the whole code and the input so that you can get some more help

Comment: Im open to suggestions yes. What is the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It's writing out twice because you output your StringBuilder (`out.write(str.toString())`) for the line (`linha`) every time you iterate through it, which will be at least the number of words in the lookup list.

Move the `out.write()` statements outside the loop and you should be fine.

***Note*** this will only find one match in each line for each word.  If you need to find more than one, the code is a little more complicated.  You need to introduce a `while` loop instead of your `if` test for matching, or you could consider using [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) using a regular expression based on your word `palavras[i]`.  Ensuring you respected the capitalisation of the original is not simple there, but possible.

---

#### Fixed version

```
static void bold(char bold, BufferedReader orders, BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out) 
        throws IOException
{
    String linha = in.readLine();
    boolean encontrou = false;
    String[] palavras = new String[Integer.parseInt(orders.readLine())];
    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++)
    {
        palavras[i] = orders.readLine();
    }

    while (linha != null)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(linha);
        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length && !encontrou; i++)
        {

            if (linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i]) != -1)
            {
                str.insert((linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i])), bold);
                str.insert(
                        (linha.toLowerCase().indexOf(palavras[i])) + palavras[i].length() + 1, 
                        bold);
            }
        }
        out.write(str.toString());
        out.newLine();
        linha = in.readLine();
    }

}
```

#### With replaceAll

```
static void bold(char bold, BufferedReader orders, BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out) 
        throws IOException
{
    String linha = in.readLine();
    boolean encontrou = false;
    String[] palavras = new String[Integer.parseInt(orders.readLine())];
    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++)
    {
        palavras[i] = orders.readLine();
    }

    while (linha != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length && !encontrou; i++)
        {
            String regEx = "\\b("+palavras[i]+")\\b";
            linha = linha.replaceAll(regEx, bold + "$1"+bold);
        }
        out.write(linha);
        our.newLine();
        linha = in.readLine();
    }

}
```

---

***P.S.*** I've left the found boolean (`encontrou`) in, although it is not doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Richard, btw can you explain me why it only bolds the first occurrence it encounters?

Comment: Ha - yes - I was just expanding my answer to include that as I noticed that problem / feature.  I'll update my answer to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

This merits a regular expression replace of WORD-BOUNDARY + ALTERNATIVES + WORD-BOUNDARY.

```
String linha = in.readLine(); // Read number of words to be bolded.
String[] palavras = new String[Integer.parseInt(orders.readLine())];
for(int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++){
    palavras[i]=orders.readLine();
}

// We make a regular expression Pattern.
// Like "\\b(him|her|it)\\b" where \\b is a word-boundary.
// This prevents mangling "shimmer".
StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("\\b(");
for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        regex.append('|');
    }
    regex.append(Pattern.quote(palavras[i]));
}
regex.append(")\\b");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

boolean encontrou = false;
linha = in.readLine(); // Read first line.
while(linha != null){
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(linha);
    String linha2 = m.replaceAll(pattern, "*$1*");
    if (linha2 != linha) {
        encontrou = true; // Found a replacement.
    }
    out.write(linha2);
    out.newLine();
    linha = in.readLine(); // Read next line.
}
```

A replaceAll (instead of replaceFirst) then replaces *all* occurrences.